# i look some example of using Swish Search Engine Extension in php

Tags: php, search-engine, swish

did somebody use this Extension in php or have an example of code,

edit :
i want to hear an opinion on this Extension if somebody deal with it.

a tutorial with code , large examples ..

Comment: Perhaps you could make your question clearerm. What exactly do you want? how it's used? (see the docs) Performance information? pros and cons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.swish.php You can even find example code.

I haven't used swish myself though so I can't vouch for it. I have, however, been pleasantly surprised with Sphinx

Comment: not to evangelize too much, but you might want to go with one of the better-known php-compatible search engines like sphinx, lucene, or xapian. Personally I'd recommend Sphinx , but honestly, I haven't tried the other two yet.

Answer (score 0):

I'll google it for you, you lazy jerk

http://www.pixel2life.com/tutorials/swish_and_swishmax/swish_with_php_mysql/

=)

Comment: the result is not what i look is SWiSH Max , not relevant , thank anyway